# Using SQL Like operation for many values on many columns

Tags: postgresql, sql-like

I am trying to write some SQL to query a Customer Account table, I would like to populate a new column called Product as name of each product, if any of the 5 product description columns contain 'Alpha','BETA', 'Gamma', 'Omega', 'Delta', 'Sigma' and 50 other products. If an account has 2 of the products mentioned in any of the 5 columns, then I need it to be duplicated so that there are 2 records showing each product.
Thank you!

This is what I have so far but only looking for 1 single product of Alpha, I need this for 56 products.

```
Select ID, Account, Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4, Product5
from AccountTable
Where Product1 like '%lpha%'
or Product2 like '%lpha%'
or Product3 like '%lpha%'
or Product4 like '%lpha%'
or Product5 like '%lpha%'
```

Comment: Start by normalising your database schema. You shouldn't have 56 columns for different products in your table to begin with.